# Unfortunately my app has stopped working

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments

Here is my login activity class where i want to do login after login it show the map but when i run the app it show unfortunately stopped login

loginActivity.java

```
package com.ivb.login;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity{
     EditText edtemail,edtPassword;
        Button btnLogin;
        String strUsername,strPassword;

      @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);
            edtemail = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edt_email);
            edtPassword = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edt_passwrd);
            btnLogin = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    strUsername = edtemail.getText().toString().trim();
                    strPassword = edtPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                    if(strUsername.equals("needin@gmail.com") && strPassword.equals("needin123"))
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,LoginSuccess.class).putExtra("usr",(CharSequence)strUsername));
                     else 
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Invalid UserName or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);

            // Listening to register new account link
            registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Switching to Register screen

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }

}
```

loginsuccess.java

```
package com.ivb.login;

import javax.security.auth.PrivateCredentialPermission;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginSuccess extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.second);


            try {
                // Loading map
                initilizeMap();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent in = getIntent();
            if (in.getCharSequenceExtra("usr") != null) {
                final TextView setmsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showmsg);
                setmsg.setText("Welcome \n "+in.getCharSequenceExtra("usr"));               
            }

            }

    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap =((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }
}
```

[image: This the werror code which is shown in log cat]

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ivb.login"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <permission 
        android:name="com.ivb.login.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.ivb.login.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature 
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ivb.login.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="sensor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity android:name="com.ivb.login.RegisterActivity"
                  android:label="Register New Account"></activity>
          <activity android:name="com.ivb.login.LoginSuccess"></activity>
           <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyC-2jAJ7MEkho_gJv7KLeb-tHrU2zHDUQU" />
           <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

second.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LoginSuccess" >
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="5dip" >
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/showmsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textSize="20dip" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@layout/header_gradient" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:src="@drawable/logo1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_email"
                android:layout_width="209dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Enter Email Address"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:typeface="normal" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_passwrd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Enter password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="133dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="#acd28a"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="15dip"
                android:text="Login" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/link_to_register"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Need an account?sign up"
                android:textColor="#0b84aa"
                android:textSize="20dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You are getting ClassCastException, you need to post real stacktrace instead of image and tell us the line where you are getting error.

Comment: when i comile the app there is no error in that when i put the credential while login it show your app is unfortunetely crashed

Comment: Post your xml file for both activities.

Comment: first of all post your xml layout, then clean your project and test again

Comment: Where is your layout `second` code? Can you post your second layout code?

Comment: @ user3110424 i had posted the above second.xml

Comment: Curiouus as to why you are casting String to CharSequence? String itself implements CharSequence. You dont need to cast it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/showmsg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:textSize="20dip" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</TextView>
```

to

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/showmsg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:textSize="20dip" >
</TextView>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

this is because your < /TextView> was closed after fragment class so you got this error.

Also change here

```
 startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,LoginSuccess.class).putExtra("usr",strUsername));
```

and also in your ***LoginSuccess*** Activity

```
        Intent in = getIntent();
        if (in.getStringExtra("usr") != null) {
            final TextView setmsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showmsg);
            setmsg.setText("Welcome \n "+in.getStringExtra("usr"));               
        }
```

That means you have to declare this part in your manifest file...

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true/>
```

and must use latest updated Google Play Service.

Comment: @ piyush thanks it works there is one Error here in logcat says google map android api V2 only support device with open gls 2.o and above what is this plz do tell me

Comment: Okay must be sure that you are running your application with Google APIs which your target SDK for running app

Comment: kk yes i am ruuning the app with google api and target sdk is 18

Comment: But your project runs properly ? Show the map?

Comment: @vaib Also must remember that your Emulator support Google APIs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46650/discussion-between-vaib-and-piyush-gupta)